# Setting a controller action inside link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help with allowing users to click "Follow/Unfollow" link and have the action take place on the user show page. Currently I have the action sitting inside a popup and I don't know how I can set it inside a link action so there would be no need for a popup.

I tried rendering the forms on the show page but that does not show as I expected.

show.html.slim:

```
        - if current_user.following?(@user)
      = link_to follow_popup_user_path(@user), class: 'profile_btn save_btn', :'data-mfp-src'=>'#follow_div', remote: true do
        = image_tag 'start_icon.png'
        span Unfollow
      - else
        = link_to follow_popup_user_path(@user), class: 'profile_btn save_btn', :'data-mfp-src'=>'#follow_div', remote: true do
          = image_tag 'start_icon.png'
```

_follow.html.slim:

```
= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f|
  div
    = f.hidden_field :followed_id
    = f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

_unfollow.html.slim:

```
= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f|
  = f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large"
```

Relationships controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship] [:followed_id] )
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    redirect_to @user
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a form for this, just pass the correct params to a nested route for relationships, then handle the specifics in the `user` model `follow` and `unfollow` methods. Try something like this:

## users/show.slim

```
- if current_user.following?(@user)
  = link_to new_user_relationship_path(id: current_user.id, followed_id: @user.id), class: 'profile_btn save_btn' do
    = image_tag 'start_icon.png'
    span Unfollow
- else
  = link_to user_relationship_path(id: current_user.id, followed_id: @user.id), method: delete, class: 'profile_btn save_btn' do
    = image_tag 'start_icon.png'
```

## routes

```
resources :users do
  resources :relationships
```

## relationships_controller

```
def create
  @user = User.find(user_params(:id))
  @followed_user = User.find(user_params(:followed_id))
  @user.follow @followed_user
  redirect_to @user
end

def destroy
  @user = User.find(user_params(:id))
  @followed_user = User.find(user_params(:followed_id))
  @user.unfollow @followed_user
  redirect_to @user
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:followed_id, )
  end
```